# mysql delete row based on value from another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table where I would like to delete rows with `INNER JOIN` where the `WHERE` clause is based on a value in another table. The `primary_key` in Table 2 is a `foreign_key` in Table 1.

Table 1

```
table_1_id  |  customer_id  |  table_2_id
-----------------------------------------
     1      |      5        |       1 
     2      |      5        |       2 
     3      |      5        |       3
```

Table 2

```
table_2_id   |    value
-----------------------
   1         |      0 
   2         |      0 
   3         |      1
```

I want to delete rows from Table 1 where the `value` in Table 2 is equal to `0`. So in this example the `DELETE` statement should delete the first two rows in Table 1, since I use `INNER JOIN` to connect the two tables.

I tried this but it doesnt exactly do what I want. This statement always deletes all the rows in Table 1 instead of the first two only.

```
DELETE t1
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON (t1.table_2_id = t2.table_2_id) 
WHERE t1.customer_id = '5' 
AND t2.value = '0'
```

Comment: Try to put your where clause in () and see what happens

Comment: Its works fine in [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/210938/1)

Comment: I cannot replicate this behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are thinking too complicatedly. You want to delete from table 1 where a condition is met:

```
delete from t1 where customer_id = 5 and t2_id in (select t2_id from t2 where value = 0);
```

Comment: I should have just put in the answer instead of commenting ; -) well done

Comment: The OP is not thinking too complicatedly. The OP's solution is entirely appropriate to the context described. The 'problem', whatever it is, lies elsewhere.

Comment: @Strawberry: Haha you got me there. I must admit I didn't look much at OP's delete statement, for joining the tables is just complicating matters for such task. However, you are right, OP's delete statement should work as well. Maybe there are records in table 2 the OP is not aware of, which can easily be checked by running my subquery separately.

Comment: ...or running the OP's query as a SELECT

Comment: i dont know what I'm doing wrong, but it seems to work with this. Thank you. I cant really figure out why the query I have wouldnt work, because I dont really see what's wrong woth the logic. But it works now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I cannot replicate this behaviour:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1;

CREATE TABLE table1
(table_1_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,customer_id INT NOT NULL
,table_2_id INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES
(1,5,1),
(2,5,2),
(3,5,3);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table2;

CREATE TABLE table2
(table_2_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,value TINYINT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO table2 VALUES
(1,0),
(2,0),
(3,1);

SELECT * FROM table1;
+------------+-------------+------------+
| table_1_id | customer_id | table_2_id |
+------------+-------------+------------+
|          1 |           5 |          1 |
|          2 |           5 |          2 |
|          3 |           5 |          3 |
+------------+-------------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)

SELECT * FROM table2;
+------------+-------+
| table_2_id | value |
+------------+-------+
|          1 |     0 |
|          2 |     0 |
|          3 |     1 |
+------------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

DELETE t1
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.table_2_id = t2.table_2_id
WHERE t1.customer_id = 5
AND t2.value = 0
;

SELECT * FROM table1;
+------------+-------------+------------+
| table_1_id | customer_id | table_2_id |
+------------+-------------+------------+
|          3 |           5 |          3 |
+------------+-------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

See. Works just fine.

Comment: that is weird indeed. I tried it even in my mysql database, no results. Everything seems the same as mine

Comment: You mean, if you copy-and-paste the above into your systemm, it doesn't work? Excuse my incredulity.